# Some questions about $d$-primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Here :

https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C7%2C13%2C31%2C103%2C109%2C151&sort=&language=&go=Search

the primes are mentioned which remain prime if the digit $1$ is inserted at
any position, including at the beginning or at the end. Let's call them
$1$-primes. There are analogue sequences in OEIS for $3$-primes, $7$-primes
and $9$ primes.

Such primes are rare : Below $10^8$ , there are $80$ $1$-primes , $122$ $3$-primes , $81$ $7$-primes and $100$ $9$-primes.

Larger examples :

$178,681,513$ is $1$-prime.

$363,437,383$ is $3$-prime.

$707,879,629$ is $7$-prime.

$950,291,093$ is $9$-prime.

Questions :

> Is it known if there are finite are infinite many $d$-primes for any $d=1,3,7,9$ ?
>
> Can a number be a $d$-prime for every $d=1,3,7,9$ ? (I conjecture this is
>     impossible, there is no such number below $10^6$) ?
>
> Which numbers below $10^9$ are $d$-primes for at least two $d's$ with $d=1,3,7,9$ (Such as $37$, which is both $3$-prime and $9$-prime) ?

Comment: Between $10^8$ and $10^9$, the numbers of $d$-primes with $d=1,3,7,9$ are $23,29,28,42$.